# Why is there a difference in output between Python and Rust code for reading output of DigiUSB.print() function over USB?

Tags: python, rust

I am trying to write a code for reading output of DigiUSB.print() function over usb, but when I ran the code, the output was not as expected. I tried the code provided by Digistump over the GitHub repository and its output was as expected. I tied to find problems in my code but to no avail.

My Rust Code:

```
use std::{io::Write, process::exit};

use rusb::{request_type, Device, DeviceList, Direction, GlobalContext, Recipient, RequestType};


fn main() -> rusb::Result<()> {
    // Find and open the USB device handle
    let device_desc = || -> Option<rusb::Device<rusb::GlobalContext>> {
        let mut temp: Option<Device<GlobalContext>> = None;
        for device in DeviceList::new().unwrap().iter() {
            let descriptor = device.device_descriptor().unwrap();
            if descriptor.vendor_id() == 0x16c0 && descriptor.product_id() == 0x05df {
                temp = Some(device)
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        temp
    }();
    let device_desc = match device_desc {
        Some(a) => a,
        None => {
            println!("Device Not Found");
            exit(0);
        }
    };

    let request_type = request_type(Direction::In, RequestType::Class, Recipient::Device);
    let request = 0x01;
    let value = 0x00;
    let index = 0x00;
    loop {
        let handle = device_desc.open();
        match handle {
            Ok(hand) => {
                let buf: &mut [u8] = &mut [0];
                let response = hand.read_control(
                    request_type,
                    request,
                    value,
                    index,
                    buf,
                    std::time::Duration::from_secs(1),
                );
                match response {
                    Ok(_) => {
                        std::io::stdout()
                            .flush()
                            .expect("Error while flushing Buffer");
                        print!("{}",char::from(buf[0]));
                        std::io::stdout()
                            .flush()
                            .expect("Error while flushing Buffer");
                    }
                    Err(_) => std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500)),
                }
            }
            Err(_) => std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)),
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Output:

```
Hello Wrl
Hell Word
Helo World
Hello orld
Helo Wold
HellWorldHelloWorld
Hello Wr
```

[Python Code](https://github.com/digistump/DigisparkExamplePrograms/blob/master/Python/DigiUSB/source/read.py):

```
#/usr/bin/python

#
# Written for PyUSB 1.0 (w/libusb 1.0.3)
#
# Includes functionality to retrieve string descriptors
#
# Author: follower@rancidbacon.com
#
# Version: 20091021
#

#
# Assumes 'UsbStreamDemo1.pde' is loaded on Arduino and 
# LEDs are present on pins 11, 12 and 13.
#

import usb # 1.0 not 0.4


import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from arduino.usbdevice import ArduinoUsbDevice


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        theDevice = ArduinoUsbDevice(idVendor=0x16c0, idProduct=0x05df)

        print "Found: 0x%04x 0x%04x %s %s" % (theDevice.idVendor, 
                                              theDevice.idProduct,
                                              theDevice.productName,
                                              theDevice.manufacturer)
    except:
        pass




    import sys
    import time

    while 1 == 1:
        try:
            theDevice = ArduinoUsbDevice(idVendor=0x16c0, idProduct=0x05df)
            try:
                sys.stdout.write(chr(theDevice.read()))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            except:
                # TODO: Check for exception properly
                time.sleep(0.5)
                
        except:
            # TODO: Check for exception properly
            time.sleep(1)
```

arduino.usbdevice:

```
#/usr/bin/python

#
# Written for PyUSB 1.0 (w/libusb 1.0.3)
#
# Includes functionality to retrieve string descriptors
#
# Author: follower@rancidbacon.com
#
# Version: 20091022
#

import usb # 1.0 not 0.4


def getStringDescriptor(device, index):
    """
    """
    response = device.ctrl_transfer(usb.util.ENDPOINT_IN,
                                    usb.legacy.REQ_GET_DESCRIPTOR,
                                    (usb.util.DESC_TYPE_STRING << 8) | index,
                                    0, # language id
                                    255) # length

    # TODO: Refer to 'libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii' for error handling
    
    return response[2:].tostring().decode('utf-16')


REQUEST_TYPE_SEND = usb.util.build_request_type(usb.util.CTRL_OUT,
                                                usb.util.CTRL_TYPE_CLASS,
                                                usb.util.CTRL_RECIPIENT_DEVICE)

REQUEST_TYPE_RECEIVE = usb.util.build_request_type(usb.util.CTRL_IN,
                                                usb.util.CTRL_TYPE_CLASS,
                                                usb.util.CTRL_RECIPIENT_DEVICE)

USBRQ_HID_GET_REPORT = 0x01
USBRQ_HID_SET_REPORT = 0x09
USB_HID_REPORT_TYPE_FEATURE = 0x03


class ArduinoUsbDevice(object):
    """
    """
    
    def __init__(self, idVendor, idProduct):
        """
        """
        self.idVendor = idVendor
        self.idProduct = idProduct

        # TODO: Make more compliant by checking serial number also.
        self.device = usb.core.find(idVendor=self.idVendor,
                                    idProduct=self.idProduct)

        if not self.device:
            raise Exception("Device not found")


    def write(self, byte):
        """
        """
        # TODO: Return bytes written?
        #print "Write:"+str(byte)
        self._transfer(REQUEST_TYPE_SEND, USBRQ_HID_SET_REPORT,
                       byte,
                       []) # ignored


    def read(self):
        """
        """
        response = self._transfer(REQUEST_TYPE_RECEIVE, USBRQ_HID_GET_REPORT,
                              0, # ignored
                              1) # length

        if not response:
            raise Exception("No Data")
        
        return response[0]
    

    def _transfer(self, request_type, request, index, value):
        """
        """
        return self.device.ctrl_transfer(request_type, request,
                                        (USB_HID_REPORT_TYPE_FEATURE << 8) | 0,
                                         index,
                                         value)


    @property
    def productName(self):
        """
        """
        return getStringDescriptor(self.device, self.device.iProduct)

    
    @property
    def manufacturer(self):
        """
        """
        return getStringDescriptor(self.device, self.device.iManufacturer)
```

Output:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: As a side note, `let buf: &mut [u8] = &mut [0];` is not very idiomatic. Generally you would instead have `let mut buf = [0u8];` which would give you a mutable array of one element.

Comment: Is either your Rust or Python code giving the expected output, or are they both wrong?

Comment: @nigh_anxiety python code is giving the expected output where as rust code is not. Python code was provided by digistump GitHub repository.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have an immediately-invoked closure there, either. Rust supports returning values from anonymous blocks. You can also just use `Iterator::find()` like so: `let device_desc = DeviceList::new().unwrap().iter().find(|d| { let desc = d.device_descriptor().unwrap(); desc.vendor_id() == 0x16c0 && desc.product_id() == 0x05df });`. Basically those 12 lines at the start of `main()` can be turned into 4.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for additional advice.